# Grafana + InfluxDB + telegraf

Tags: influxdb, grafana, telegraf

I'm using grafana to monitor network device. As u can see at screen1 , I got many interfaces for monitor, 28 physical interfaces + many virtual (vlan).
Graph show me all interfaces, but I want and opportunity to choose interface from the drop-down list. Then I found that I can solve this problem with "variables".
I make one variable and I can choose interface I want, but it didn`t effect on graph when I chose custom interface.

[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4utKN.png)

My variable:

[Variable config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtJXD.png)

And my db query:

```
SELECT derivative(mean("ifHCInOctets"), 1s) *8 AS "Input", derivative(mean("ifHCOutOctets"), 1s) *8 AS "Output" FROM "autogen"."interface" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval), "ifDescr" fill(null)
```

Comment: try: `.. WHERE ("interface" =~ /^$ifDescr$/) `

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII I add it to variable query, right? If so, it doesn't help.

Comment: No its an Error in your db query

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII, I try this one, but it didn`t work for me:
```SELECT derivative(mean("ifHCInOctets"), 1s) *8 AS "Input", derivative(mean("ifHCOutOctets"), 1s) *8 AS "Output" FROM "autogen"."interface" WHERE ("interface" =~ /^$ifDescr$/)```

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII is right, add your variable to data query filter.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE "interface" =~ /^$ifDescr$/

lose the brackets around the query in the grafana query when you make the dashboard. That should work. That's how i filter host names anyway, so my full query is

```
SELECT mean("usage_idle") * -1 + 100 FROM "cpu" WHERE "host" =~ /^$Server$/ AND "cpu" = 'cpu-total' AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($Interval) fill(null)
```

That should help piece together the query you need. You could just use Grafana's query builder, and just change the where clause to use the regex value for the variable

[Query Builder in Grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFmGK.png)

The brackets is right if you are writing in TICK script or querying the database directly from the cli. Grafana uses slightly different query syntax.